# hide a table row tr contain a specific label using css

Tags: html, css, html-table

Hello please help me  here is  a table

```
<table class="variations" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="label"><label for="pa_1ef722433d607dd9d2b8b7"><span>Ships From</span></label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="label"><label for="pa_color"><span>color</span></label></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to hide each table row tr that had label for="pa_1ef722433d607dd9d2b8b7"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using js .You can use `document.querySelectorAll()` to access all tr inside the table. Then you can check for occurrence of `label for="pa_1ef722433d607dd9d2b8b7"` inside each.
Let me show you the code which is self explanotory-

```
window.onload=()=>{
var elem=document.querySelectorAll("tr");
var i;
for(i=0;i<elem.length;i++){
  var obj=elem[i];
  if(obj.innerHTML.toString().includes('label for="pa_1ef722433d607dd9d2b8b7"')){
      obj.style.display="none";
    }
}
}
```

In css it will be harder to access parent element, so it is better to use some javascript

Comment: thank you very much for your replay how can I execute this code on wordpress?

Comment: Simply put this code in <script></script> tag in your html document.

Comment: Note:  check the changes in answer code. It is important to execute code after loading of document. So I have used ***document.onload***. By the way if your problem is solved mark it as answer

Comment: thank you for help sir , I tried your script but unfortunately it doesn' work

Comment: Can you tell me the error it is showing.it seems correct to me. Just go to website and press ctrl+shift+ i to open console. Sorry but currently i am on a mobile so unable to test. By the way I have edited something, try the new code.

Comment: when I have execute this code in my WordPress website doesn't happen anything  , I tried also add your script on the head of my website using inspect element , it doesn't work

Comment: Add it inside script tag at end of body

Comment: I have add it  at the end of the body but it doesn't work , you can see your code on the attached image 
https://snipboard.io/z8FyDG.jpg

Comment: I have found my mistake and corrected it. Now check. Actually i have changed document.onload to window.onload and replaced double inverted comma to single inverted comma in include() method

Comment: By the way you can in case of errors check the console by following ways, it list all errors- https://balsamiq.com/support/faqs/browserconsole/#:~:text=To%20open%20the%20developer%20console,select%20More%20Tools%20%3E%20Developer%20Tools.&text=The%20console%20will%20either%20open%20up%20within%20your%20existing%20Chrome,to%20select%20the%20Console%20tab.

Comment: have you changed the code as per the edit in answer, it is working 100% correct in jsfiddle see- https://jsfiddle.net/k0wz7ct2/. further your website has no error